# Mostrar espacio ocupado por nuevos archivos dentro de varias carpetas

Tags: linux, consola, línea-de-comandos

Tengo un servidor de correo en Plesk. Cada día, el servidor sube de tamaño casi 0,5 Gb. Es demasiado para la cantidad de usuarios que tengo.

Sé que por un lado tengo el comando find (`find -type f -mtime -7`) que me permite buscar los archivos en un rango de tiempo específico... y por otro, du (`du -hs *`), que me permite saber el espacio utilizado por cada carpeta, pero no sé como unirlos.

Me gustaría saber en que carpeta se han recibido esos correos tan grandes. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ¿Que tipo de servidor de correo usas?

Comment: Intenta esto  find .  -type f -printf '[%TY-%Tm-%Td]\t%s\t%f\n' | sort -n | tail -25 | cut -f2- -d" "